# How to move items inside div relative to its parent div

Tags: html, css

I successfully display the "choose" button inside a div in a position where i want it to be. but soon i realize that it only works when i hover over it (i am experimenting with hover and positioning on div), but without hovering the 3 buttons only appears on one specific spot in which i don't understand why it's there.

maybe you guys know the answer to this problems. thanks

sorry for the messy code here, i am very new.

[code snippets](https://jsfiddle.net/notfishbutfish/r67Lfca0/5/)

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      ul {
        display: flex;
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      #header-img {
        display: flex;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #video {
          width: fit-content;
        }
      }

      #container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 200px auto 200px auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }

      .choices {
        background-color: rgb(241, 241, 111);
        width: 250px;
        height: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      }

      .choices .pilih {
        position: absolute;
        left: 40%;
        top: 350px;
      }

      .choices:hover {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
      }

    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/16/05/30/11574bb301599cc.jpg" alt="" id="header-img">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">How it works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Fish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15467239/fish) So, You want to show choose button in each div at same position?

Comment: @cse_vikashgupta exactly! i wonder if i can use absolute position, i thought it's best using absolute bcs its relative to parents (each div). maybe you have better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you set any element position:absolute, It sets its position relative to body(by default).
2. In your case, To position relative to specific container, you need to set it's parent (with class choices) as
   "position: relative"

```css
 header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      ul {
        display: flex;
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      #header-img {
        display: flex;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #video {
          width: fit-content;
        }
      }

      #container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 200px auto 200px auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }

      .choices {
        background-color: rgb(241, 241, 111);
        width: 250px;
        height: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        position: relative;
      }

      .choices .pilih {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        top: 50%;
      }

      .choices:hover {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
      }
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/16/05/30/11574bb301599cc.jpg" alt="" id="header-img">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">How it works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="choices">
        <form action="">
          <input type="button" value="choose" class="pilih">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```